# images are not shown at given positions when included margin-left and margin-right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm showing some images on the chart. They are showing fine but issue is when included the `margin-left` and `margin-right` to give some space to show the chart.

included css code:

```
#chart1 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow : hidden;
        margin-left: 60px;
        margin-right: 60px;
    }
```

js code:
Below js code is used to show the images at a particular location on the chart.
The below code works when the chart is occupied to 100% , but when included the above css code, the image positions are not shown at given timeframes..

```
overlay.style.left = (overlayBounds.x / (timelineWidth / 100) ) + '%';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#timeline {
  position: relative;
}
```

Then you will need to update

```
.overlay {
  ...
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `overlay.style.left = ( overlayBounds.x / timelineWidth ) * 100 + '%';`

Comment: #timeline{
  position: relative;
}

Comment: I have tried the same as suggested by you above but could not succeed. I have raised another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916399/image-is-not-shown-on-the-given-location-when-used-css-attributes-to-give-some-m . Any inputs?