# image is not shown on the given location when used css attributes to give some margin space

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, google-visualization, overlays

I'm showing some images on the chart. The position to display the images are not showing correctly when included margin-left and margin-right properties to the chart.

Please find the demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/vr7R9KsvC2GuS7kfoIBp?p=preview
css code:

```
#chart1 {
  padding:0.5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow : hidden;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

#chart2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow : hidden;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

#chart3 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow : hidden;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}
```

Below line is used to calcuate and display the image at particular location.

```
overlay.style.left = (overlayBounds.x / (timelineWidth / 100) ) + '%';
//overlay.style.left = ( overlayBounds.x / timelineWidth ) * 100 + '%'; //tried, but not successful
```

Comment: @Randy Collier - Any inputs on this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response.
I have noticed that your div element 'chart2' needs to have the `position: relative`. Also the `<img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/512/star_wars/16/clone_old.png" class="overlay" style="top: 250px; left: 39.1057%;">`, the `top: 250px` needs to be changed to 5px or something small.

Take a look at [css positioning](https://tomelliott.com/html-css/css-position-child-div-parent) or [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).
Also in the chrome developer tools, you can inspect the dom elements to see where they are at and change the css rules to better understand the css.